# Como sacar los top 5 de cada vendedor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-2008, subconsultas

quisiera saber como puedo obtener un top 5 de productos por antiguedad, tenemos un campo que registra la antiguedad en dias, como hacer una consulta sql que me muestre de los vendedores que tenemos?
esta es la tabla, todo esta en sql server

```
create table Cliente
(
 idEmpleado int identity (1,1) primary key,
 nombre varchar (30)not null,
 producto varchar (30)not null,
 DiaAnt int
 )
```

tengo estos datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedo sacar individualmente de cada vendedor :

```
Select top 5 DiaAnt, nombre, producto from Cliente
 where nombre = 'Juan Perez'
 order by DiaAnt desc
```

necesito lo mismo pero para todos los vendedores.

Comment: Creo que la tabla no tiene un buen diseño... Acaso tienes aparte una tabla de empleados? y si es así, en que campo se registra el id del empleado?. El campo `nombre` a qué hace referencia, al nombre del cliente o del empleado?. El campo `idEmpleado` cumple la función de identificar a cada empleado o solo es un id del registro de la venta?. Te sugiero que estudies un poco los [principios básicos de las bases de datos](https://www.ohmyroot.com/bases-de-datos-principios-basicos/#:~:text=principios:).

Comment: Algo adicional, en las etiquetas mezclas `mysql` con `sql-server`. Si bien ambas son `sql` hay cierta diferencia en la sintaxis. Por favor, deja solo la etiqueta que corresponda al motor que utilizas.

Comment: @DjCrazy es una tabla de muestra, la original esta en el server de mi trabajo, pero basicamente es un top 5 de cada vendendor, nombre seria vendedor, un top 5 por vendedor, no se si entiende

Comment: Es importante que agregues la mayor cantidad de datos posibles a la pregunta, cuáles tablas existen? que datos contienen? para saber como hacer el `JOIN`, sin esto es difícil determinar cómo debería quedar estructurado el query. Pásate por [esta sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que comprendas a que me refiero.

Comment: no hay mas tablas solo es una, por eso solo publique esa unica tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Existen muchas alternativas a lo que propones.

Una simple, y sobre todo didáctica. Utilizamos una tabla de expresión común para conseguir los diferentes nombres de los clientes.

A la salida de la cte, usamos el operador apply, relacionando los nombres con el operador Top.

```
create table Cliente
(
 idEmpleado int identity (1,1) primary key,
 nombre varchar (30)not null,
 producto varchar (30)not null,
 DiaAnt int
);
go
insert into dbo.Cliente (
nombre,producto, DiaAnt)
values
('Juan Valdivia','Computadora',40),
('Juan Valdivia','Equipo de sonido',120),
('Juan Valdivia','Laptop',140),
('Juan Valdivia','Teclado',30),
('Juan Valdivia','Mouse',45),
('Juan Valdivia','Computadora',100),
('Juan Valdivia','Equipo de luz',90),
('Juan Valdivia','Computadora',60),
('Juan Valdivia','Computadora',10),
('Alejandra rojas','Computadora',10),
('Alejandra rojas','Equipo de sonido',40),
('Alejandra rojas','teclado',50),
('Alejandra rojas','Computadora',25),
('Alejandra rojas','Laptop',15),
('Alejandra rojas','Computadora',50),
('Alejandra rojas','Laptop',15),
('Alejandra rojas','Computadora',30);
go
```

[image: Res]

Pero todas las soluciones a aplicar requieren de algo que hay que determinar, para que no sea a libre albedrío.

```
With cte as 
(
    Select distinct  nombre from dbo.cliente
)
Select ca.* from cte
cross apply 
(
    Select top(5) * from dbo.cliente c
    where c.nombre = cte.nombre
) ca
```

`Select top(5)`....requiere de un order by, que deberías de proporcionar. Bien sea producto, DiaAnt, o idEmpleado. Además ese order by debería de ser determinista. Por tanto no debería de haber dos registros que cumplieran el order by sin ser diferenciables.

Por ejemplo si pones order by producto.... y resulta que el registro 5 Tiene computadora con 100 unidades y el registro 6 tiene computadora con 40 unidades, es posible, que te devuelva ante la misma consulta una vez el de 100 unidades y otra el de 40.

[Operador apply](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/06/27/operador-apply/)

[Cte](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los primeros N valores de cada grupo, normalmente se utiliza `ROW_NUMBER()` para identificarlos dentro de un CTE que funciona como una vista creada al vuelo.

```
WITH cteCliente AS(
    SELECT DiaAnt, 
           nombre, 
           producto,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY nombre ORDER BY DiaAnt) AS orden
    FROM Cliente
)
SELECT DiaAnt,
        nombre,
        producto
FROM cteCliente
WHERE orden <= 5
ORDER BY orden;
```